# Interpolate a double into a Swift string

Tags: ios, string, swift, string-formatting

I am trying to create an NSPredicate with the format:

```
var aPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude >= %d AND latitude <= %d AND longitude >= %d AND longitude <= %d", latitudeGreater, latitudeLesser, longitudeGreater, longitudeLesser)
```

The tutorial I had been following was using dates and used `%@`, and I was getting an error because `latitude >= nil` wouldn't work. When I finally realized I needed a different interpolation format, I tried to look up the correct way to use a `double`, but I can't seem to find any information on this. `%d` like I have in my code now gives me `latitude >= 0` as well as 0s for the rest. How would I go about getting the whole `double` to go properly into the space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per Apple's [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html),

> `%f` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`).
>
> `%d` | Signed 32-bit integer (`int`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.... I was just trying stuff while I waited for an answer, and %f worked great. I thought "d" would be for double and "f" would be for float, but then I would think "d" would work just fine... anyone have any info on this?

Comment: From ["Predicate Format String Syntax"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) in the "Predicate Programming Guide": *"The format string supports printf-style format specifiers such as %x (see Formatting String Objects)."* ... with a reference to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html  which in turn references to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html . It's all documented :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the double into \() like this: \(latitudeGreater)

From the Swift Programming Guide :  `let​ ​appleSummary​ = ​"I have ​\(​apples​)​ apples."`

Comment: This is String interpolation. It will not work with NSPredicate. You need to use predicate formatting as specified in the docs.

Comment: It might work with numbers, but I would not recommend it because it will definitely fail with strings which must be properly quoted.

Comment: Oh yes I stand corrected. I just looked at his title "How do I interlope a double into a string in Swift?" and that would be the answer, except in this case he is using it for a predicate, so he needs the Objective-C style interpolation.